# Sharing audio on facebook using open graph

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, audio, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share the audio content on facebook using og tags so that audio should play in the facebook window only.

Here is the code which I have written:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.songdew.com/test_manish.html"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sgmedia/13122/photos/t_ce0284c1ad98c8e79c3f3af7b8c297.jpg"/>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="335931163095578"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="3. undead redemption" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.songdew.com/test_manish.html"/>
<meta property="og:audio" content="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sgmedia/18037/tracks/f7a43fcd2f8a15a0a1322bf3ac2429.mp3">
<!--<meta property="og:audio:title" content="manish23">
<meta property="og:audio:artist" content="Mkumar">
<meta property="og:audio:album" content="itsnew">  -->
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="application/mp3">
</head>

<title>This is test</title>

<style type="text/css">

#share-buttons img {
width: 35px;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
}

</style>
<body>Thiis is a test Page


</body>

</html>
```

However, the audio doesn't get played there. I am not getting what is the issue in this code. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t share audio tracks in a way so that they play inline right now.

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music clearly states right on top of the page, that is only available to a limited set of white-listed Facebook partners as this time.

A possible alternative is to embed it as a video (flash and/or mp4). Whether you make that video just play the audio, and have the visual content just be black or whatever, or use the video to transport additional information about the audio track (like who’s the artist, maybe a cover artwork, …), is up to you.